# chartjs data labels - character level font colour control

Tags: chart.js

I want to set font colour at character level (or word level) in my data-labels in chartjs. See before and after image below.

For example, if my data-label is `0.89` I would like the paint the `0` as yellow, `8` as blue and `9` as red.

[image]

Sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hooks-zcg91?file=/src/components/LineChart.jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik you can set the individual collors of the letters with the datalabels plugin, you will need to write your own custom plugin for that, what you can do is provide an array of collors to the `color` property to give each entry a different collor: https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-leaf-pxmzm

```js
datalabels: {
      display: true,
      color: ["black", "green", "blue", "pink", "purple"],
      align: "end",
      padding: {
        right: 2
      },
      labels: {
        padding: { top: 10 },
        title: {
          font: {
            weight: "bold"
          }
        }
      },
      formatter: function (value) {
        return "\n" + value;
      }
    }
```

**Edit:**

after looking at the code the datalabels plugin uses to render the labels its not possible to color individual characters, if you want that you will need to write your own custom plugin:

```js
const customDatalabalesPlugin = {
  id: 'customDatalabels',
  afterDatasetsDraw: (chart, args, opts) => {
    const {
      ctx,
      _metasets
    } = chart;
    _metasets.forEach((meta) => {
      meta.data.forEach((datapoint) => {
        const lineHeight = ctx.measureText('M').width;
        const dpVal = datapoint.parsed.y;
        const text = dpVal.toString();
        const textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
        const color = opts.color || 'black';

        if (typeof color === 'string') {
          ctx.fillStyle = color;
          ctx.fillText(text, (datapoint.x - textWidth / 2), (datapoint.y - lineHeight));
        } else if (Array.isArray(color)) {
          let x = datapoint.x - textWidth / 2;

          for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            const char = text.charAt(i);

            ctx.fillStyle = color[i % color.length];
            ctx.fillText(char, x, (datapoint.y - lineHeight));
            x += ctx.measureText(char).width;
          }
        } else {
          console.error('Invalid color type provided');
        }
      })
    })
  }
}

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12.4, 19.234, 3.23213, 5.4, 2, 3],
      borderColor: 'pink'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      customDatalabels: {
        color: ['pink', 'green', 'orange'], // Color each character individual collor
        // color: 'pink' // Color whole label this collor
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [customDatalabalesPlugin]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks like the array of colours are applied at individual data labels, how do I apply the array of colours within a single data labels at character level. I've updated my post.